# group node based on xpath predicate

Tags: c#, xpath

I have strings of xpath like

```
/root/parent/child
/root/parent/child[1]
/root/parent/child[2]
```

In the c# code i am checking if the xpath exist in XmlDocument and cloning it like this

```
//Get the parent node of the node to be cloned
XmlNode NodeTobeCloned = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(oRow[0].ToString());
XmlNode DuplicateNode = NodeTobeCloned.CloneNode(true);
DuplicateNode.InnerText = sValue;
//Insert the node after the last child of a commoon parent
NodeTobeCloned.ParentNode.AppendChild(DuplicateNode);
```

I am getting a result like

```
<root>
<parent>
<child/>
<child/>
<child/>
</parent>
</root>
```

I want a result like

```
<root>
<parent>
<child/>
</parent>
<parent>
<child/> -- [1] -predicates elements
</parent>
<parent>
<child/> -- [2] -predicates elements
</parent>
</root>
```

how can i append to xmldocument using c#
thank you

Comment: /root/parent/child and /root/parent/child[1] refer to the same node.  Did you actually mean [2] and [3]? What does the original XML look like? Are you saying that you want to create additional `<parent>` nodes to put the `<child>`ren in?

Comment: Yes its my mistake to assume predicates starts from 0. you are right and it starts from 1
Yes I want to create additional parent nodes to put the child in.Actually I have a logical group stored as xpath strings like 

/root/parent/child
/root/parent/child[2]
/root/parent/anotherchild[2]
I want to group based on predicates
<root>
<parent>
<child/>
</parent>
<parent>
<child/>
<anotherchild/>
</parent>
</root>

Comment: any pointers to the problem?

Comment: I don't think this is a very good design and I think the parameters of the problem are not very well defined.  What is your actual task at hand?  Why are you using XPath to designate nodes to create?  XPath is almost always intended for querying XML, not adding to it.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, could you post the original XML and what "oRow[0].ToString()" means please